# View data from a controller function with 2 models

Tags: php, codeigniter

I trying to get Banner Images from DB via controller and model.

My controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    //put your code here
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('home_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array();

        $data['bannerInfo'] = $this->home_model->selectBanner($banner_id);
        $data['result'] = $this->home_model->selectCategory($category_id);
        $data['banner'] = $this->load->view('banner',$data, TRUE);
        $data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('home_message',$data,TRUE);
        $data['title'] = 'NZ Furniture Products ';
        $data['keywords'] = 'furniture bangladesh';

        $this->load->view('home', $data);
   }
```

My model class:

```
class Home_Model extends CI_Model {
    // put your code here
    public function selectCategory($category_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_category');
        $this->db->order_by("category_id", "desc"); 
        $query_result=  $this->db->get();
        $results = $query_result->result();

        return $results;
    } 

    public function selectBanner($banner_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_banner');
        $this->db->where('banner_id',$banner_id);
        //$this->db->order_by("product_id", "desc"); 
        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $results = $query_result->result();

        return $results;
    } 
$
```

Views:

home_message:::

```
<?php foreach ($result as $values)  { ?>
<div class="single_product">
<div class="product_image">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/category/<?php echo   $values->category_id ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $values->category_image ?>" /></a> 
    </div>
    <span class="category_title"> <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/category/<?php echo $values->category_id ?>"> <?php echo $values->category_name ?></a> </span>
 </div>

<?php } ?>
```

**banner**

```
<div>
<?php foreach ($bannerInfo as $values) {   ?>
<?php echo $values->banner_image ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Wats the issue u re facing??

Comment: What exactly the issue? Banner not displaying? And home_message and banner view files are different?

Comment: Failed to view Banner Images in Banner view pages But OK on home_message Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show all banners. You have to remove where clause. Default ordering is desc.

Controller file:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller 
{
  public function __construct() {
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->model('home_model');
  }

  public function index() {
    $data = array();
    $data['bannerInfo'] = $this->home_model->selectBanner();
    $data['result'] = $this->home_model->selectCategory($category_id);
    $data['banner'] = $this->load->view('banner', $data, TRUE);
    $data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('home_message', $data, TRUE);
    $data['title'] = 'NZ Furniture Products ';
    $data['keywords'] = 'furniture bangladesh';
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
  }
}
```

Model file:

```
class Home_Model extends CI_Model
{
  public function selectCategory($category_id)
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_category');
    $this->db->order_by("category_id", "desc"); 
    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $results = $query_result->result();
    return $results;
  } 

  public function selectBanner($order_by = "desc")
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_banner'); 
    $this->db->order_by("banner_id", $order_by);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry to say you that It is not working :::

In home page there are 2(two) variables::: 
     <?php echo $banner; ?> ::: it comes from view/banner page
     <?php echo $maincontent; ?>:: it comes from view/home_message page

I want to show banner images into view/banner page (with controller and model)...

Comment: Hmm.. Just realized, you didnt set $banner_id in this line: $data['bannerInfo']=$this->home_model->selectBanner($banner_id);

Comment: So what $banner_id as int?

Comment: You getting banners by banner_id from model and you didnt set $banner_id in controller page. Ex: $banner_id = 1;

Comment: So $banner_id change depending what? Why you put $banner_id? Didnt you want all banners show homepage?

Comment: Yes I want all banners to show in homepage

I just called $banner_id for descending or ascending

Comment: Updated, please try again. Ok, one minute! I fixing again

Comment: It is not working ... please let me know where I have to change ??

Comment: I wrote controller and model file, try again

Comment: If you get error again, please write into controller file end of the index() function : var_dump($data['bannerInfo']);